# Получение только измененной части LiveData<List>

Tags: android, observer, livedata

Активно изучаю LiveData в андроид и хотел бы разобраться со следующим вопросом.
Андроид устройство - клиент, через сокет цепляется к серверу. Сервер периодически присылает какие-то сообщения, среди них есть события, которые необходимо отрисовывать на вьюшке.
Я использую mvvm паттерн. На события, пришедшие от сокета, подписывается репозиторий:

```
class EventRepository : IEventRepositoty {

    private companion object {
        val MAX_EVENT = 20
    }
    private val mEventList = MutableLiveData<EvictingQueue<EventModel>>()
    val eventList : LiveData<EvictingQueue<EventModel>> = mEventList
    .....
}
```

В репозитории хранится *mEventList*, в который я складываю события, пришедшие от сервера.
Вопрос в том, что если *ViewModel* подпишется на *eventList*, то при записи нового события во *ViewModel* сработает *observer*, аргументом которого будет весь новый список. Но на вьюшке уже большая часть списка отрисована, и мне надо только вставить новый item.
Решение, которое пришло в голову: события записывать не в *LiveData*, а в обычный `list<EventModel>`, а в *LiveData* держать только один *EventModel*
Но что-то мне не нравится данный вариант, ибо при старте я запрашиваю последние события с сервера, и их придет список. Есть вариант держать `LiveData<EvictingQueue<EventModel>>`, но писать туда только список новых элементов (если событие одно, то, соответственно, список размера 1).

Может, есть какой-то более удобный способ получить только измененную часть списка?

Comment: От слова differences, DiffUtil. Он автоматически будет применять алгоритм сравнения, по дефолту Майерса. Но переопределить параметры сравнения в объектах вам необходимо, так же ListAdapter это базовый класс RecyclerView поэтому достаточно добавить arch 3dLib , pagingLib и у вас появится возможность использовать новый recycler и более того в google примеры с использованием LiveData только через DiffUtil, странно что автор сделав одно не знает как доделать другое

Comment: @pavlofff  спасибо, вроде то, что нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь идет о `RecyclerView`, рекомендую вам обратить внимание на [новый адаптер `ListAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter.html) из библиотеки поддержки v7. Он обязывает реализовать механизм `DiffUtil`, который позаботится о вычислении изменений между новыми данными и уже имеющимися в адаптере и автоматически произведет нужные манипуляции (добавит, удалит, изменит соответствующие айтемы). Таким образом вы отдаете адаптеру актуальный список целиком (а не в ручную отбираете новые элементы), он же позаботится о остальном.

При этом работать будет все полностью автоматически - при изменении данных в репозитории они будут изменяться и в виджете без каких либо действий с вашей стороны.

[Пример](https://medium.com/@trionkidnapper/recyclerview-more-animations-with-less-code-using-support-library-listadapter-62e65126acdb)