# Уведомление в приложение при изменение данных

Tags: java, android

Приложение список: значение - количество
Как сделать проверку раз в 15 секунд обновились ли эти количества и если да то вывести уведомления или сделать определенное действие.
Изначально данные парсятся с сервера в формате json и с помощью адаптера передаются в RecyclerView.
Понимаю, что нужно сделать сохранение этих данных и сравнивать их, если меняется то выводить что-то. 
Подскажите как будет это эффективнее и проще.

Comment: ну, например, LiveData позволяет подписаться на изменение данных и при событии срабатывает обсервер, где вы можете обработать эти изменения. то же есть в RxJava. В Android Architecture Component вообще комплексное решение по [автоматической обработке изменения данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/852530/177345) с использованием ListAdapter для RecyclerView.

Comment: Еще как вариант [DiffUtil](https://startandroid.ru/ru/blog/504-primer-ispolzovanija-android-diffutil.html).

Comment: да, ListAdapter использует DiffUtil, как обязательную к реализации часть адаптера